# Cannot convert list of date strings to timestamp and get the average

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, strtotime

What i am trying and cannot manage to make it work is to convert the below date strings into timestamp format and then after inserting this values to a timestamp field in MySQL get the average arrival (first entry of each day) and departure time( last entry of each day).
When i try to use strtotime in the place month i get the day.

```
11/1/2018 2:58:03 PM
11/1/2018 12:38:08 PM
11/1/2018 12:29:27 PM
11/1/2018 12:26:06 PM
11/1/2018 12:22:41 PM
11/1/2018 10:58:54 AM
10/31/2018 1:35:41 PM
10/31/2018 11:23:50 AM
10/31/2018 11:15:01 AM
10/31/2018 9:32:43 AM
```

The code i execute is the below for the conversion:

```
$file_date = '11/30/2018 7:46:06 PM';
$file_date = str_replace('/', '-', $file_date);
$file_date = substr($file_date, 0, strpos($file_date, ' ', strpos($file_date, ' ')+1));
$file_date = strtotime($file_date);
echo $file_date.' ';
echo date('Y-m-d', $file_date).' ';
```

What am i doing wrong here? I am getting instead of the correct value **1970-01-01**

Thank you very much in advance for your responses.

Comment: Why all that messing around with the dates? You can replace all of that with just `echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($file_date));` using the original value of, for example, `'11/30/2018 7:46:06 PM'`.

Comment: @dave is right. there is no need for the first three lines.

Comment: Thank you @Dave

Comment: Also Don't forget to check your PHP version before writing any code on date functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it helps. It's converting String date into a DateTime Object and Formatting as your wish and converting to the timestamp.

```
<?php
$file_date = '11/30/2018 7:46:06 PM';
$date = new DateTime($file_date);
$result = $date->format('m-d-Y');
// result is = 11-30-2018

$datetoTimeStamp =  $date->getTimestamp();

echo $datetoTimeStamp; // OUTPUT İS 1543607166
```

Now you can find all these values ​​with the help of a loop and find the average by dividing the sum by the number of values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply it works!
Any idea about the query i have to execute in order to get the average arrival and departure time every day?

Comment: I can only help a few hours later. And you can approve my answer as a solution please :)

Comment: I would be more than happy to get a response for the sql query! thank you again